# How to stop href links from preforming the slidetoggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I stop my `sub-menu` href links slidetoggling the `sub-menu`? I only want the my 'sub-menu' ul's to toggle when their respective link is clicked?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPVRxq

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
        $('ul', this).slideToggle('fast');

        $('#arrow', this).toggleClass('fa fa-angle-left fa fa-angle-down');

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-header">
                    Stuff will be in here
                </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboards <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dash 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dash 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dash 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dash 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Graphs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-inbox"><span class="inbox-number">11</span></i> Mailbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Widgets</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Forms <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Form 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Form 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Form 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>


        <div id="admin-top-grey-bar">
            <div class="green-menu-button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for something...">
        </div>
    <div id="main-area-wrapper">
        <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event to the link inside your li, instead of the complete li, then use siblings to select the ul next to it

```
$('.dropdown>a').on('click', function () {
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your click event triggers at any child element of '.dropdown'. The best way to avoid that is to bind trigger to other element inside '.dropdown' that visible. For instance - your link.

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Forms <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
```

Or you can disable event on your hidden ul via jquery :not() . But I don't think this is a good practice.

```
$('.dropdown:not(ul)').on(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please give me an example, I tried binding it but it didn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

edit: updated  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grewrvyv/), you want something like that?

then just modify the selector from `'.dropdown'` to `'.dropdown a'`

Comment: That didn't work. When you click the sub links e.g 'dash 1' or 'dash 2' it still closes the menu when I want it to stay open.